# Stop a recursive AJAX call on a button click and start it again on a button click

Tags: html, jquery

I am calling ajax after each 5 secs to update my data and I need to stop that call when a button is clicked.
My ajax function is:

```
function get_text(){
    var text = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getIt.php",
            async: false
        }).complete(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){get_text();}, 5000);
        }).responseText;

        $('#editor_Content').html(text);
}
```

this function is called at

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   new get_text(); 
}
```

I need to stop this call when a button is clicked and start this call again when the same button is clicked again. Any suggestions?

My button click code is

```
function editit(){ 
    var myVar = document.getElementById("editor_Content").getAttribute("contenteditable"); 
    if(myVar=='true'){         
        document.getElementById("editor_Content").setAttribute("contenteditable", "false"); 
        document.getElementById("editbtn").setAttribute("value","Edit Text"); 
    } else{ 
        document.getElementById("editbtn").setAttribute("value","Done Editing"); 
        document.getElementById("editor_Content").setAttribute("contenteditable", "true"); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the result of `setTimeout` and use it in a call to the `clearTimeout` function like so:

```
function get_text(){
    var text = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getIt.php",
        async: false
    }).complete(function(){
        window.getTextTimeoutId = setTimeout(function(){get_text();}, 5000);
    }).responseText;

    $('#editor_Content').html(text);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    get_text(); 
} 

function editit(){ 
    var myVar = document.getElementById("editor_Content").getAttribute("contenteditable"); 
    if(myVar=='true'){         
        if(window.getTextTimeoutId){
            window.clearTimeout(window.getTextTimeoutId)
            window.getTextTimeoutId = null;
        }
        document.getElementById("editor_Content").setAttribute("contenteditable", "false"); 
        document.getElementById("editbtn").setAttribute("value","Edit Text"); 
    } else{ 
        document.getElementById("editbtn").setAttribute("value","Done Editing"); 
        document.getElementById("editor_Content").setAttribute("contenteditable", "true"); 
        if(!window.getTextIntervalId) //edited for not to create another call. fixed!
            window.getTextTimeoutId = setTimeout(get_text, 0);
    } 
}
```

But for your purposes I think `setInterval` and `clearInterval` would work better. Here is what your new code would look like:

```
function get_text(){
    var text = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getIt.php",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    $('#editor_Content').html(text);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
     window.getTextIntervalId = window.setInterval(get_text, 5000); 
} 

function editit(){ 
    var myVar = document.getElementById("editor_Content").getAttribute("contenteditable"); 
    if(myVar=='true'){         
        if(window.getTextIntervalId){
            window.clearInterval(window.getTextIntervalId)
            window.getTextIntervalId = null;
        }
        document.getElementById("editor_Content").setAttribute("contenteditable", "false"); 
        document.getElementById("editbtn").setAttribute("value","Edit Text"); 
    } else{ 
        document.getElementById("editbtn").setAttribute("value","Done Editing"); 
        document.getElementById("editor_Content").setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
        if(!window.getTextIntervalId) //edited for not to create another call. fixed!
            window.getTextIntervalId = setInterval(get_text, 5000);
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate using a code of this? like my button click funcion is:

`function editit(){
 var myVar = document.getElementById("editor_Content").getAttribute("contenteditable");
 if(myVar=='true'){
  document.getElementById("editor_Content").setAttribute("contenteditable", "false");
document.getElementById("editbtn").setAttribute("value","Edit Text");

 }
 else{
  document.getElementById("editbtn").setAttribute("value","Done Editing");
  document.getElementById("editor_Content").setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");

 }
}`

Comment: what? sorry, I didn't understand that.

Comment: I have written a code that disables an area to edit text and then I want my AJAX call to update that area and when the same button is clicked I want my AJAX call to stop updating that editing area.

Comment: I think you should use the `setInterval` solution

Comment: The work is done but in an opposite way. But when I change it, it has no effect.. :/

Comment: it doesn't stop all the calls. It just stop the call it generated. Same problem persists.

Comment: There must be another issue in your code. the call to `clearInterval` will stop the next call to get_text however if there is a call currently running I don't think it will interrupt it.

Comment: yes exactly. I have catered it. Thank you very much for your help! :)